# Extension companies spamming answers

Tags: discussion, spam

Recently I see a lot off Low Quality and First Post reviews coming in where a certain company is clearly spamming for their extensions.

The posts are well targeted (the extension would probably solve the problem), but the post text is clearly slick and commercial in tone of voice: It is describing the extension in more than one superlative.

Most post are provided with a direct link to the extension or the main website. Today I got the first post without a link, just naming the extension.

Of course, the SE moderation system catches most of these spam posts, but is there also another way? Should we look into means beyond what the SE platform offers? Could we contact the extension builder directly to discuss this issue with them and request not to spam, <del>or to advertise for their extensions only when it is really contributing</del>?

Or should we simply let the SE system do it's job and just passively react to this by keep flagging this when these posts appear in the review queues (as this "[possible duplicate](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/429)" suggests)?

In this specific case, this is about the LitExtension extensions provider (with users [Hai Thiet Le](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/24445/hai-thiet-le) and [Joe](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/24496/joe) (suspended) spamming the posts). Should we contact them to pursue them to get them to refrain from these activities?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we restrict module developers advertising in Magento SE?](http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/429/how-can-we-restrict-module-developers-advertising-in-magento-se)

Comment: Ok, I see the similarities with that specific question. I'm seeing if we can look for solutions beyond what SE provides (flagging, moderator attention, user profile suspension)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am the one who flagged most of these spams and moderators took right action against those threads/answers. I think moderator even deleted those user accounts and it is highly appreciable.

However, it seems that LitExtension providers continues their spamming in daily basis. So I have the same opinion that of @7ochem. We should contact these extension providers and let them know.

I think stackExchange do not have such provisions. But we, as a community should think about contacting them.

Also we should be more vigilant. I have notified about this spamming to Marius privately. But even after he took action, I saw the cheap marketing continues from these extension providers. That's why I openly described about this in #MageStackDaySlack.  So be vigilant guys( n girls).

Flag them. Flag them and Flag them

Comment: At first I contacted a few of them and suspended their accounts, but the spam didn't stop. So I destroyed a few accounts. I don't think there is a better way...so just like you said...flag, flag, flag.

Comment: @Marius : In these two days, I couldn't find much spams. In order to check what I am doing is filtering questions with the tag `migration` and took `newest` list. May be you can also use it to track them out. Please do this filtering once in a day and distroy them. Thanks for your care and actions. Long Live His Higness :-)